# add to all values in object using spread

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know if there is a shorthand for this?

```
let zx = { a: 1, b: 10};
let as = { a: 20, b: 1};

as += ...zx;    //Ideas on a shorthand here? 

console.log(as);
```

desired result:  {a: 21, b: 11}

Comment: This is no concatenation operator for objects, so no, there is no shorthand.

Comment: No, there's no shorthand for this. You'll need to use a loop with something like `forEach` or `reduce`.

Comment: Probably not possible using spread, but you can achieve the result by using `Object.keys` and `forEach`: `Object.keys(as).forEach(k => as[k] += zx[k])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys` method in combination with `forEach` by passing an `arrow` function as argument.

```js
let zx = { a: 1, b: 10};
let as = { a: 20, b: 1};

Object.keys(as).forEach(key => as[key] += zx[key])

console.log(as);
```

Another approach is using `reduce` method.

```js
let zx = { a: 1, b: 10};
let as = { a: 20, b: 1};
as = Object.keys(as).reduce(function(obj, k) {
    obj[k] = zx[k] + as[k]
    return obj;
}, {});
console.log(as);
```